# Controller design with DQ transform

Tags: control-systems

I'm reading [this paper](http://ijiet.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/19.pdf) on a 3-phase rectifier control.  3-phase rectifiers are usually connected to 50-Hz or 60-Hz grid. One popular control strategy is to transform the 3-phase currents and voltages to the DQ axes. Basically, the 3 voltages are changed in two "DC" voltages named $d$ and $q$. Same thing for currents, the 3 currents are changed to $d$ and $q$.

[As the $d$ and $q$ values are now "dc" values.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-quadrature-zero_transformation) One can use PI controllers in order to reach a steady-state error of 0. So far so good. However, keep in mind that in this new axis, a frequency of 0 Hz corresponds to a frequency of $\pm 60$ Hz in the real world. (or $\pm 50$ Hz)

Here's my problem :

They manipulate the transfer functions as if they were on the same basis

For instance the Process transfer function is :

$$G_p(s) = \frac{1}{R+sL}$$

The process transfer function is in the "real-world" where DC is 0 Hz.

Then they apply an internal-model control to design the controller

Controller : $$G_c(s) = Kp+\frac{Ki}{s}$$

They use $$Kp = \frac{L}{\lambda}$$ and  $$Ki = \frac{R}{\lambda} $$

However, the controller works on the $dq$ axes where 0 Hz is $\pm 60$ Hz.

**Am I wrong in thinking that you cannot simply design the controller this way?**

Edit : Just to clarify, I don't doubt that their gains are good and yield a stable controller. I just doubt the rationale behind the gain calculations.